# htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to write an htaccess rewrite rule. But it is not redirecting,

This is my present rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ question.php?qkey=$1
```

that will show a url like sitename/questionkey and redirect it perfectly.

Now Iam trying to show a url like sitename/questioncatagory/questiontititle

Iam trying to use the following rule, but it is not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ question.php?qkey=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's probably better for clarity and maintenance to replace your ([a-zA-Z0-9]) with ([\w]+)

Secondly, your new rule doesn't work because of the caret ^ character.  In the beginning, it indicates 'match beginning of the line', which surely doesn't apply 3 times total in the regex.  Remove the two later ^ carets (and then make use of your additional captured groups somewhere with $1, $2, et c).

Lastly, you probably don't need to match the end of the line with the $ character.  This is unfriendly to many URLs, for example ones with a trailing slash.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([\w]+)/([\w]+) question.php?qkey=$1&cat=$2&qtitle=$3
```

Comment: I added the adjusted line to my answer, but it still requires your own implementation of $2 and $3 (the question/category/question_title) portion of your url.

Comment: Thanks it is working :) .. Is there any chance to hide the questionkey in the url. I would like to show the url as   sitename/questioncatagory/questiontititle.

Comment: This is the url now  sitename/29481751ffe886a64f9b0c9a/catagory/title. I would like to show the url as sitename/catagory/title.  Could u please help me ...

Comment: Glad it worked out! Would be pleased to get the accepted answer, indeed! As far as hiding, you won't be able to hide anything that is part of the original URL, unfortunately.  If that questionkey is being generated and placed into the website, no amount of rewriting will be able to hide it; the only means to obscure it would be to replace qkey with an arbitrarily generated value...(one that could be translated/hashed back to your original) but this wouldn't add much value to you as the dev and won't pretty up your URL either.

Comment: In other words, yes, you can OMIT the whole question key, but somewhere, somehow with the remaining two pieces of info (category and title), you'd have to have a whole new php function to derive the questionkey from, which might not be possible in your design.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions and help . Iam 100% satisfied . thank you sir....

Comment: Happy to have helped.  Feel free to tick the checkbox to mark this question as solved and answer accepted :)

Comment: I would like to show the url as sitename/catagory/title/questionkey. Iam trying to use the following rule. But it is not working              RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([\w]+)/([\w]+) question.php?qkey=$1&cat=$2&qtitle=$3